# Changing the pointing of assets from old server to new server

Tags: plugins, themes

The assets [javascripts,css and other files] are loading from the old server. I need to point them all to the new server url.How to do it?
[image]

They have to be replaced with the new domain url.

Answer (score 0):

Usually scripts and styles are loaded with `wp_enqueue_script` or `wp_enqueue_style` in the theme's `functions.php`. That's the most common scenario.

This function takes an `$src` parameter which is the absolute URL to the resource, and the best practice is to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` to retrieve the URL to the folder containing the script. This way, if the site is moved, the URL will change with it.

It might be that those were hardcoded strings. That's why they're still the old ones.

See examples below
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#user-contributed-notes

Scripts and styles loaded from a plugin should use `plugins_url` in the $src parameter.
`wp_enqueue_style( 'prm_style', plugins_url('/assets/style.css', __FILE__ ) );`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! 
The below is how my function.php looks:
<?php
if ( !function_exists( 'bezel_parent_css' ) ){
  function bezel_parent_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bezel-parent-style', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'bundle-css' ) );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'style');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style');
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bezel_parent_css', 14 );


function evereteam_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'everteam-script', '/script.js', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'evereteam_enqueue_script' );

Comment: Can you please let me know how to fix this 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Then how to fix these hardcoded strings and replace them with the new server url

Comment: Ah sorry, looks like those highlighted URLS are loaded from a plugin "prm_addon". Can you look in that plugin's code? The scripts woulld also be loaded with `wp_enqueue_script` but use `plugins_url` in the $src parameter

Comment: Not only "prm_addon" plugin 
Many plugins scripts are loading the same

Comment: https://codeshare.io/GAbAre
This is the code of prm_addon

Comment: The below link is for Tabs.php code:
https://codeshare.io/5ekAyx

Comment: in the first file, the assets are missing the `plugins_url` function in the $src parameter

Comment: are you sure all URLs have been updated? can you run WP CLI? what do you get for `wp option get siteurl` and `wp option get home`?

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/PY3P6rY/site-url-wp.jpg
Same set in database

Comment: Maybe there's a filter on `plugins_url` or `home_url` or `site_url` somewhere? `add_filter( 'home_url...`

Comment: Or it could be some full page caching?

Comment: Regarding plugins_url 
u mean replacing this wp_enqueue_style( 'prm_style', '/wp-content/plugins/prm_addon/assets/style.css' ); by 
wp_enqueue_style( 'prm_style', plugins_url('/assets/style.css', __FILE__ ) );

Comment: yes, `__FILE__` (it's a magic constant) https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5zQ88N
This the link of parent theme code

Comment: sorry, I'm stumped. seems like there's something else at play unrelated to how scripts are enqueued. Maybe an htaccess file that's overwriting some URLS? just a wild guess. I noticed these lines: `update_option('home','https://partners.intalio.com');
update_option('siteurl','https://partners.intalio.com');` you shouldn't do that, because it's going to write to the database on every page load. you can remove that code